# C# - Deserializing nested json to nested Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, system.text.json

I'm using .net core 3.1 and library System.Text.Json

How can I deserialize nested json object to Dictionary<string, object>, but the expectation is that based on json property type I'll get proper C# type:

```
String -> string
Number -> int/double
Object -> Dictionary<string, object>
```

By default - if I try to deserialize to Dictionary<string, object> - basically every object is a JsonElement.
I'd like it to be of type as mentioned above.

Any idea how it can be achieved?

Comment: Could you explain better and show us some example about what you want.

Comment: You will need to write a custom `JsonConverter` to do that.  Unlike newtonsoft it isn't implemented automatically, perhaps because `Utf8JsonReader` only recognizes numbers, it doesn't actually parse them to a CLR type (thereby avoiding arithmetic overflow or roundoff errors).

Comment: Deserialize to `string, string` then parse yourself?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order to deserialize free-form JSON into .Net primitive types instead of `JsonElement` objects, you will need to write a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to), as no such functionality is provided by `System.Text.Json` out of the box.

One such converter is the following:

```
public class ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter : JsonConverter<object>
{
    FloatFormat FloatFormat { get; init; }
    UnknownNumberFormat UnknownNumberFormat { get; init; }
    ObjectFormat ObjectFormat { get; init; }

    public ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter() : this(FloatFormat.Double, UnknownNumberFormat.Error, ObjectFormat.Expando) { }
    public ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter(FloatFormat floatFormat, UnknownNumberFormat unknownNumberFormat, ObjectFormat objectFormat)
    {
        this.FloatFormat = floatFormat;
        this.UnknownNumberFormat = unknownNumberFormat;
        this.ObjectFormat = objectFormat;
    }
    
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value.GetType() == typeof(object))
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        else
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, value.GetType(), options);
        }
    }
    
    public override object Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonTokenType.Null:
                return null;
            case JsonTokenType.False:
                return false;
            case JsonTokenType.True:
                return true;
            case JsonTokenType.String:
                return reader.GetString();
            case JsonTokenType.Number:
            {
                if (reader.TryGetInt32(out var i))
                    return i;
                if (reader.TryGetInt64(out var l))
                    return l;
                // BigInteger could be added here.
                if (FloatFormat == FloatFormat.Decimal && reader.TryGetDecimal(out var m))
                    return m;
                else if (FloatFormat == FloatFormat.Double && reader.TryGetDouble(out var d))
                    return d;
                using var doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
                if (UnknownNumberFormat == UnknownNumberFormat.JsonElement)
                    return doc.RootElement.Clone();
                throw new JsonException(string.Format("Cannot parse number {0}", doc.RootElement.ToString()));
            }
            case JsonTokenType.StartArray:
            {
                var list = new List<object>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    switch (reader.TokenType)
                    {
                        default:
                            list.Add(Read(ref reader, typeof(object), options));
                            break;
                        case JsonTokenType.EndArray:
                            return list;
                    }
                }
                throw new JsonException();
            }
            case JsonTokenType.StartObject:
                var dict = CreateDictionary();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    switch (reader.TokenType)
                    {
                        case JsonTokenType.EndObject:
                            return dict;
                        case JsonTokenType.PropertyName:
                            var key = reader.GetString();
                            reader.Read();
                            dict.Add(key, Read(ref reader, typeof(object), options));
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new JsonException();
                    }
                }
                throw new JsonException();
            default:
                throw new JsonException(string.Format("Unknown token {0}", reader.TokenType));
        }
    }
    
    protected virtual IDictionary<string, object> CreateDictionary() => 
        ObjectFormat == ObjectFormat.Expando ? new ExpandoObject() : new Dictionary<string, object>();
}

public enum FloatFormat
{
    Double,
    Decimal,
}

public enum UnknownNumberFormat
{
    Error,
    JsonElement,
}

public enum ObjectFormat
{
    Expando,
    Dictionary,
}
```

And to use it, deserialize to `object` (or `dynamic` if configured to use `ExpandoObject`) as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter(floatFormat : FloatFormat.Double, unknownNumberFormat : UnknownNumberFormat.Error, objectFormat : ObjectFormat.Expando) },
    WriteIndented = true,
};
dynamic d = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json, options);
```

Notes:

- JSON allows for numbers of arbitrary precision and magnitude, while the .Net primitive numeric types do not.  In situations where some JSON number cannot be parsed into a .Net primitive type, the converter provides the option to either return a `JsonElement` for the number, or throw an exception.

  The converter could be extended to attempt to deserialize unsupported numbers to [`BigInteger`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64788895/3744182).
- You can configure the converter to use `double` or `decimal` for floating point numbers, and `Dictionary<string, object>` or `ExpandoObject` for JSON objects.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Y6hI6).

Comment: Great post, answer, and converter for those times apis are created in the wild west by gungho FuLl StAcK DeVoLoPeRs. +1

Comment: This is now also documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#deserialize-inferred-types-to-object-properties