# Force System.Text.Json to deserialize in CamelCase

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I am trying to build a JsonElement (or similar) using a camelCase convention from a PascalCase string using System.Text.Json. Is there a way to enforce that behavior?

```cs
var jsonString = "{\"Property1\":\"s\", \"PropertyCamel\":{\"PropertyNested\":\"g\"}, \"PPP\":[{\"NestedList\":\"1\"}]}";
var deserialized = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(jsonString,
    new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
        DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    });
var serialized = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(
    deserialized,
    new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
        DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    });
// deserialized outputs property names in PascalCase
```

I have also tried deserializing -> serializing -> deserializing but without success.

Is there a way of doing so?

Comment: Set `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` to `true` and serialize again.

Comment: @Beltway it doesn't work either. I believe since it is a JsonElement object it doesn't run the code on `JsonCamelCaseNamingPolicy`

Comment: Can't you map it to a transient object? By default `System.Text.Json` should use camelCase when serializing from shorthand getters written in PascalCase.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to **load or deserialize** a [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?) or [`JsonElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement) and convert it to camelCase during the loading process.  `JsonDocument` and `JsonElement` are just read-only, structured views of the utf-8 JSON byte sequence from which they were loaded and as such there's no way to transform the view during (or after) the parsing process.  For confirmation, `JsonDocument`, `JsonElement` and [`Utf8JsonReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader) are all `sealed` and `JsonElement` has no publicly accessible constructor so there simply isn't an extension point to inject custom transformation of property names.

As an alternative, you could camel-case the property names **during re-serialization** by creating the following custom [`JsonConverter<JsonElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to):

```
public class JsonElementConverter : JsonConverter<JsonElement>
{
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonElement value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        switch (value.ValueKind)
        {
            case JsonValueKind.Object:
                var policy = options.PropertyNamingPolicy;
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                foreach (var pair in value.EnumerateObject())
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName(policy?.ConvertName(pair.Name) ?? pair.Name);
                    Write(writer, pair.Value, options);
                }
                writer.WriteEndObject();
                break;
            case JsonValueKind.Array:
                writer.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var item in value.EnumerateArray())
                    Write(writer, item, options);
                writer.WriteEndArray();
                break;
            default:
                value.WriteTo(writer);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    public override JsonElement Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        using var doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
        return doc.RootElement.Clone();
    }
}
```

And then re-serializing your `JsonDocument.RootElement` using [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer) like so:

```
using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);

JsonNamingPolicy policy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new JsonElementConverter() },
    PropertyNamingPolicy = policy,
    WriteIndented = true // Or false, if you prefer
};

var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(doc.RootElement, options);
```

Notes:

- Be sure to serialize the `JsonDocument.RootElement` rather than the `JsonDocument`.  If you serialize the document directly the converter is never invoked.
- In .NET 6 it should be possible to transform the property names during deserialization/loading using a custom converter by deserializing to the new [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-6.0) DOM, whose elements can be constructed and modified directly by applications code.
- As an alternative, if you don't require use of `JsonElement`, you could consider deserializing to an `ExpandoObject` or similar and remapping the properties during deserialization by extending `ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974452/3744182) to *[C# - Deserializing nested json to nested Dictionary<string, object>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65972825/3744182)* to do the necessary name transformation.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kgiAIH).