# How can I parse a JSON into a dynamic object allowing access to fields via dot notation using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, roslyn, system.text.json

I'm implementing a feature where a user can write an arbitrary expression that needs to be evaluated against some context. Users should be able to write expressions referring to a dynamic JSON payload.

I'm using Roslyn CSharpScript to execute the expression.

I managed to make it work using Newtonsoft, however I would like to do the same using System.Text.Json.

Working approach with Newtonsoft:

```cs
    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_Evaluate_Dynamic_Payload_Using_Newtonsoft()
    {
        // Arrange
        const string jsonPayload = """
                                    {
                                        "dog": {
                                            "name": "Slayer"
                                        }
                                    }
                                    """;
        var evaluationContext = new EvaluationContext
        {
            Payload = JObject.Parse(jsonPayload),
        };

        const string expression = @"Payload.dog.name == ""Slayer""";

        var options = ScriptOptions.Default;
        options = options.AddReferences(typeof(CSharpArgumentInfo).Assembly);
        var script = CSharpScript.Create<bool>(expression, options, globalsType: typeof(EvaluationContext));
        var scriptRunner = script.CreateDelegate();

        // Act
        var result = await scriptRunner(evaluationContext);

        // Assert
        result.Should().BeTrue();
    }
```

Not working approach with System.Text.Json:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_Evaluate_Dynamic_Payload_Using_SystemTextJson()
    {
        // Arrange
        const string jsonPayload = """
                                    {
                                        "dog": {
                                            "name": "Slayer"
                                        }
                                    }
                                    """;
        var evaluationContext = new EvaluationContext
        {
            Payload = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(jsonPayload),
        };

        const string expression = @"Payload.dog.name == ""Slayer""";

        var options = ScriptOptions.Default;
        options = options.AddReferences(typeof(CSharpArgumentInfo).Assembly);
        var script = CSharpScript.Create<bool>(expression, options, globalsType: typeof(EvaluationContext));
        var scriptRunner = script.CreateDelegate();

        // Act
        var result = await scriptRunner(evaluationContext);

        // Assert
        result.Should().BeTrue();
    }
```

This fails with `'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' does not contain a definition for 'dog'`. It seems like the parsed JsonElement is not being correctly identified as a dynamic, hence accessing the property with dot notation fails.
I know I could use `Payload.GetProperty("dog").GetProperty("name").ToString()`, but I'd much prefer keeping the dot notation (`Payload.dog.name`).

I tried parsing the JSON with `JsonDocument`, `JsonElement`, `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Text.Json using the same syntax as Newtonsoft.Json

```
var Payload = JsonObject.Parse(jsonPayload);
    
var name = (string) Payload["dog"]["name"];
var path = (string) Payload["dog"]["name"].GetPath(); //$.dog.name
```

but System.Text.Json supports only get path. IMHO Text.Json still is too raw for using. I highly recommend you to use Newtonsoft.Json. It is not ony one problem, the longer you try to use Text.Json the more problem you have. Sooner or later you will give up.

Answer (score 0):

[`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) implements [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider) which is what allows your Json.NET code to work: it dynamically forwards .NET property references to JSON property dictionary lookups, so that:

```
string name = ((dynamic)evaluationContext.Payload).dog.name;
```

Is evaluated in runtime as:

```
string name = ((JToken)evaluationContext.Payload)["dog"]["name"]?.ToString();
```

`JsonElement` and `JsonNode`, however, do not implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, so the above dynamic expression will not work with them. See [Json Deserialization of "dynamic" does not work #66638](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/66638) for confirmation.

What you could do instead is to deserialize your JSON to an `ExpandoObject`, then pass that into your `CSharpScript`.  To do that, copy `ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974452/3744182) to [C# - Deserializing nested json to nested Dictionary<string, object>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65972825/3744182).  Assuming your `EvaluationContext` type looks like:

```
public class EvaluationContext { public dynamic Payload { get; set; } }
```

You can modify your code as follows:

```
var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter(objectFormat : ObjectFormat.Expando, // Use  ObjectFormat.Expando to enable dynamic evaluation
                                                  floatFormat : FloatFormat.Double, unknownNumberFormat : UnknownNumberFormat.Error) },
    WriteIndented = true,
};
var evaluationContext = new EvaluationContext
{
    Payload = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonPayload, jsonOptions),
};
```

And the remainder should work as-is.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1pky2h).

As an alternative, since your expressions look like [JSONPath queries](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), you might consider using a 3rd party JSONPath evaluator for System.Text.Json (which does not support JSONPath itself, unlike Newtonsoft).  There are several mentioned in [Add JsonPath support to JsonDocument/JsonElement #31068](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31068) including:

- [JsonPath.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonPath.Net/)
- [BlushingPenguin.JsonPath](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlushingPenguin.JsonPath/)
- [JsonDocumentPath](https://github.com/azambrano/JsonDocumentPath).