# Get System.Object from System.Text.Json.JsonElement

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I am using the `var myObject = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<MyObject>(stream);` to deserialize a Json file into my object structure.

```cs
public class MyObject
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public object SomeObject { get; set; } // I don't know the type
}
```

The challenge is that `SomeObject` is an `object`. That means that it becomes a `System.Text.Json.JsonElement`. But I would like to have the real value instaed.

So instead of

- `{ SomeObject: "MyString" }` is now a `JsonElement ValueKind = String : "MyString"` but I would like to have a `System.String "MyString"`
- `{ SomeObject: 123 }` is now a `JsonElement ValueKind = Number : "123"` but I would like to have a `System.Int32 123`

So my question: How to make sure that the value is always converted to its real type?

Comment: check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138793/system-text-json-jsonelement-toobject-workaround

Comment: `ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974452/3744182) to [C# - Deserializing nested json to nested Dictionary<string, object>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65972825/3744182) should do what you want for primitives like `string` and `int`.  But if you need to preserve the types of non-primitive POCOs (such as `MyObject`) you will need to look into [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182) as JSON is untyped.

Comment: Do either of those two questions answer yours also?

Comment: @vhr thanks for the answer. I don't (want to) know the type however. So the `ToObject<???>()` cannot be used.

Comment: @dbc Yes your answer is working! Thanks