# System.Text.Json Serialize an Object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, system.text.json

I am trying to send an object via SignalR.
It looks like

```
[Serializable]
public class MyDataClass
{
   //Some property correctly serialized and deserialized

   public Int32 Format { get; set; }

   public required Object? Value { get; set;}
}
```

Value can be a bool, a string , an int ... , and is described by Format.

It is well serialized.

But when I deserialize, i have a `System.Text.Json.JsonElement`, and when printing it, it looks like "ValueKind ({})"

**EDIT : WITH A CUSTOM JsonConverter**

Using the suggested docs, I wrote a simple JsonConverter to handle this :

```
public class MyDataClassConverter : JsonConverter<MyDataClass>
{
    public override ViewModelExecutionVariable Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var myData = new MyDataClass();
        var properties = typeof(MyDataClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
        {
            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                if (doc.RootElement.TryGetProperty(propertyInfo.Name, out var jsonElement))
                {
                    object? value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonElement.GetRawText(), propertyInfo.PropertyType, options);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(myData , value);
                }
            }
        }
        myData.Value = FormatHelper.GetObjectValue(myData.Format, ((JsonElement)myData.Value).GetString())!;

        return myData;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyDataClass value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
    }
}
```

*And added a decorator `JsonConverter(typeof(MyDataClassConverter))]`*

*But now i have a problem when serializing a list of items:*

```
List<MyDataList> myDataList = this.GetDataList();
var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(myDataList);
```

*After this last line the program never ends.*

It works fine without the decorator, using no custom Serializer:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(myDataList)
```

and then the custom Deserializer

```
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyDataClass>>(message, new JsonSerializerOptions {Converters = { new MyDataClassConverter()}})!)
```

But it is a lot heavier than just the decorator, so I would take any suggestion to make Serialize works.

To add precision, FormatHelper.GetObjectValue() is a big switch :

```
public static Object? GetObjectValue(Int32 formatType, String? value)
{
    Object? result = null;
    switch (formatType)
    {
        case FormatTypeBase.Boolean:
            result = value == "1" || value == "True";
            break;
        case FormatTypeBase.Numeric:
            result = Double.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            break;
        case FormatTypeBase.String:
            result = value;
            break;
        //...
    }
    return result 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074304/is-polymorphic-deserialization-possible-in-system-text-json)

Comment: See second answer there, new functionality now available.

Comment: Is `Value` guaranteed to be a **primitive**?  If so rather than using polymorphic deserialization you might want to use a custom JsonConverter that recognizes JSON primitives and maps them to .NET primitives such as `ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974452/3744182) to [C# - Deserializing nested json to nested Dictionary<string, object>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65972825/3744182).

Comment: What is `FormatHelper.GetObjectValue()`?  Can you share the code for that?

Comment: Sure but it is used in the Deserialize only, and i tested it with ``System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyDataClass>>(message, new JsonSerializerOptions {Converters = { new MyDataClassConverter()}})!)``, it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

You converter basically just postprocesses one property (specifically `MyDataClass.Value`) using the value of a second property (`Format`).  This can be done most easily by implementing an [`IJsonOnDeserialized`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserialized?view=net-7.0) deserialization [callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-6-0#callbacks):

```
public class MyDataClass : IJsonOnDeserialized
{
    //Some properties correctly serialized and deserialized

    //The Value I need to deserialize to the correct type, and its format.
    public Int32 Format { get; set; } // Shouldn't this be a FormatTypeBase enum rather than an integer?
    public required Object? Value { get; set;}
    
    // A callback to convert the deserialized JsonElement to the correct primitive.
    void IJsonOnDeserialized.OnDeserialized() 
    {
        if (Value is JsonElement e)
        {
            Value = FormatHelper.GetObjectValue(Format, e.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.String ? e.GetString() : e.GetRawText());
        }
    }
}       

public enum FormatTypeBase
{
    Boolean = 1,
    Numeric = 2,
    String = 3,
}

public class FormatHelper
{
    public static Object? GetObjectValue(Int32 formatType, String? value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;  // Or throw an exception?
        Object? result = null;
        switch ((FormatTypeBase)formatType)
        {
            case FormatTypeBase.Boolean:
                result = value == "1" || value.Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // TODO: check for invalid non-Boolean string values.
                break;
            case FormatTypeBase.Numeric:
                result = Double.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                break;
            case FormatTypeBase.String:
                result = value;
                break;
            //...
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException(((FormatTypeBase)formatType).ToString());
        }
        return result;
    }       
}
```

Doing things this way completely eliminates the need to write a `JsonConverter` that falls back to default logic during serialization.  While slightly tricky, this is possible -- though not if you apply the converter directly to the type.  For details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430421/3744182) to *[How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65430420/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dp05iy).